# Uploading files greater than 2GB in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, file-upload, uploadify

I am trying to upload video files larger than 2GB on an ASP.NET MVC 3 project however the maximum file upload size for ASP.NET 4.0 seems to be at 2GB. Is there a way to exceed this limitation in ASP.NET/IIS? or what would another approach be to get around this?

I am also using uploadify as my file upload control. Any help and resources for achieving this appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: **[Can you Split the files during upload and unpacks a zip file (extracts all the entries) as mentioned here](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)**

Comment: You will need to split the file in chunks.

Comment: specify max buffer size in web-config file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my experience there is no way to upload file over 2Gb in a single request. There is a 2Gb limitation in IIS, and there is no workaround.

In .Net 4.0 and earlier there were also a 2Gb (some people say 4Gb) limitation in ASP.NET, that [was fixed in .Net 4.5](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/2642879-maximum-upload-size-in-asp-net-is-2gb-increase-it). However this fix makes a little sense because IIS itself does not support file uploads over 2Gb.

The only way to upload files over 2Gb to IIS-hosted server is to break it into pieces and upload piece by piece. Here are clients that can upload breaking a file into segments:

1. [IT Hit Ajax File Browser](http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser/)
2. [Sample WebDAV Browser](http://www.webdavsystem.com/client/browser)

Note that these clients require your server to support PUT with Range header.

Another solution is to create a HttpListener-based server. HttpListener has much less functionality comparing to IIS but it does not have any upload limitations.