# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#-4.0, file-upload, video-streaming, streamreader

I am uploading larger video files say 1 GB Size from Admin Panel but whenever i try to upload larger files i get "'System.OutOfMemoryException'" error.
Here is my code :

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
            {
                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);
                string _connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"];
                int id=1;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "update ref_Accueil set nm_Video=@nm_Video where id_Page=@id_Page";
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_Page", id);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nm_Video", bytes);
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
```

I am using Flow Player for my videos.

Here is code in my web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="3000000000" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

When i try to get larger files from database i also got this error on system.dll here is another part of code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["id_Page"]);
            byte[] bytes;
            string contentType;
            string _connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"];
            string name;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "select id_Page, nm_Video from ref_Accueil where id_Page=@id_Page";
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_Page", id);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytes = (byte[])sdr["nm_Video"];
                    //contentType = sdr["ContentType"].ToString();
                    //name = sdr["Name"].ToString();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.Buffer = true;
            //context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
            //context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            context.Response.End();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

while binding

```
private void BindGrid()
            {
                string _connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"];
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "select id_Page, nm_Video from ref_Accueil";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        DataList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        DataList1.DataBind();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: RIght now I see you set your IIS limit to more than 1 go however it looks like the asp.net limit is still at 1 go. Try increasing <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" ">  to match the IIS limit. This one is actually noted in kb rather than bytes it's set at 1 go right now.

Comment: @Simon after increasing <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" "> the error resolved but now i am getting a new error while getting video file from database.
"An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"
is there any hint what should i do ?

Comment: I believe the byte array is limited to 2 go so that may be an issue if your file is larger than that.

Comment: Can you see the code and suggest where edit  needed

Comment: I recommend you handle all file transfers piece-by-piece instead of processing all the data at one time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16517816/uploading-files-greater-than-2gb-in-asp-net-mvc-3    be it mvc or not it's fairly similar anyway.

Comment: @Sander can you give me a useful link with code in asp.net to handle file transfers piece by piece  ? I am able to upload larger size video in database but i am not getting this video at once.